# Is there a way with smbmount to mount drives with the dollar sign?

Tags: samba, smb

I am trying to do an equivalent to this:

smbmount //srv_files/f$/ /mnt/srv_files -o username=user,password=pass,rw

I am getting permission denied though, but if I do:

smbmount //srv_files/active/ /mnt/srv_files -o username=user,password=pass,rw

then it works just fine, just wondering if this type of mounting with smbmount is even possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is really a stackoverflow question, but whatever... You probably need to escape the `$` sign. $ shares are typically admin only, as well, are you connecting as an admin?

> smbmount //srv_files/f\$/ /mnt/srv_files -o username=user,password=pass,rw

Comment: Thanks, I guess it isn't a stackoverflow question, my bad. Thanks for responding anyhow easel.